How can I check if a transit visa is required for me at Beijing PEK airport?
I'm flying from Munich to Seoul soon, and I have a 5-hour layover in Beijing (PEK). I do not plan to exit the transit area. How can I check if I need a visa?
I have found some older answers with expired links; I have also checked TIMATIC to the best of my ability, but it's not entirely clear to me how the policies apply to people who don't exit the transit area.
The passports in question are Indonesian and Russian. The booking is with Air China, it's one booking from Munich to Seoul with luggage transfer.

Indonesian passport, transit in PEK:

Visa
Visa required.
TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They can obtain an entry permit on arrival and they must have documents required for the next destination. Passengers with multiple transit stops within China (People's Rep.) must have a total transit time not more than 24 hours. Exception: This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC), Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Nanjing (NKG) and Urumqi (URC). Information: This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (JFK - PVG - GUM).
Warning:
TWOV does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (e.g. JFK - PVG - GUM).

So you don't need a visa, even if you leave the transit area (you can even transit through China if you want to as long as it remains under 24 hours)
Russian passport, transit in PEK:

Visa
Visa required.
TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They can obtain an entry permit on arrival and they must have documents required for the next destination. Passengers with multiple transit stops within China (People's Rep.) must have a total transit time not more than 24 hours. Exception: This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC), Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Nanjing (NKG) and Urumqi (URC). Information: This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (JFK - PVG - GUM).
(...)
Nationals of Russian Fed. with a confirmed onward air, cruise or train ticket to a third country
within 144 hours, starting from 00:01 on the day following the day of entry. They must:

arrive at and depart from one of the following locations: Beijing (PEK), Daxing (PKX), Tianjin (TSN), Shijiazhuang (SJW), Beijing West Railway Station, Tianjin International Cruise Home Port or Qinhuangdao Sea Port; and
have documents required for the next destination. Information: This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (JFK - PVG - GUM).


Same thing, but you can even get a 144-hour (6-day) entry (as long as you remain in the Beijing region).
So no, you don't need a visa for China in either case in your situation.

Thank you, I guess that also means that we don’t need to obtain any entry permit if we don’t leave the transit zone?
